# JSON not replacing variables

Tags: json, twig, patternlab.io

I'm using Twig PatternLab.

I got a small issue with JSON and a Twig for loop.

Atom 00-h3-black.twig:

```
<h3 class="A-ChevronBlack"><a href="">{{ text.chevron }}</a></h3>
```

Molecule 00-mastertile.twig:

```
    <div class="M-DMasterTile">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="content">
        {% include "atoms-h3-black" %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Organisms 00-default2.twig:

```
    {% for post in default2 %}
          {% include "molecules-mastertile" %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And JSON inside Organism folder 00-default2.json

```
    {
      "default2" : [
        { 
          "text" : {
            "chevron" : "How to build a campfire",
            "body" : "This is the body copy"
          }
        },
        {
          "text" : {
            "chevron":"Lorem Ipsum",
            "body" : "This is the body copy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

My expectation is for the "default2" to loop twice because I've got an array with 2 items in the JSON and push the JSON content. If I take the variables out of the JSON array it shows the changes(but obviously duplicated).

What am I doing wrong here?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html#include) uses global scope and there is no variable `text` in it. Use `include with` syntax to pass variable into inner scope.

Your `Organisms 00-default2.twig` should look like this:

```
{% for post in default2 %}
      {% include "molecules-mastertile" with {'text': post.text} %}
{% endfor %}
```